# Effective, and Non-Redundant PHP code

Tags: php

I have the following PHP excerpt code:

```
foreach($afb_replacements as $afb_to_replace => $afb_replacement) {
    $sender_subject     = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $sender_subject);
    $ar_subject         = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $ar_subject);

    $final_message      = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $final_message);
    $final_message_text = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $final_message_text);

    $ar_message         = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $ar_message);
    $ar_message_text    = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $ar_message_text);
}
```

All 6 variables are replaced in the same manner (same text to replace with the same replacement in all variables with $afb_to_replace and $afb_replacement).

What I want to know is:

How can this be written more effectively? Perhaps in one line of code. I am sure there is a better way, since this is redundant code but no other solution comes into my mind at the moment. Any ideas?

I am curios about your approach!

Answer (score 5):

This should do exactly the same thing:

```
$in = array($sender_subject, $ar_subject, $final_message, $final_message_text, $ar_message, $ar_message_text);
$out = str_replace(array_keys($afb_replacements), array_values($afb_replacements), $in);
list($sender_subject, $ar_subject, $final_message, $final_message_text, $ar_message, $ar_message_text) = $out;
```

I split it onto three lines for readability.

`str_replace()` accepts arrays for search, replace and subject.

**edit:** here's an even prettier solution suggested by BoltClock

```
$in = compact('sender_subject', 'ar_subject', 'final_message', 'final_message_text', 'ar_message', 'ar_message_text');
$out = str_replace(array_keys($afb_replacements), array_values($afb_replacements), $in);
extract($out);
```

Comment: If you use `compact()` and `extract()` it saves some typing of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` accepts arrays for the subject argument (and the needle and haystack if you like). So you could do this:

```
$vars = str_replace($afb_to_replace, $afb_replacement, $vars);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$bad = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$good = array('x', 'y', 'z');
$old = array($sender_subject, $ar_subject, $final_message, $final_message_text, ...);
$new = str_replace($bad, $good, $old);
```

Or if you don't want to change your current `$afb_replacements` array, it could be done this way (stealing code from @James C):

```
$bad = array_keys($afb_replacements);
$good = array_values($afb_replacements);
$old = array($sender_subject, $ar_subject, $final_message, $final_message_text, ...);
$new = str_replace($bad, $good, $old);
```